# self join in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, self-join

```
 CustID       Name         ReferredBy
 1         Neeta Sayam  
 2         Dolly Dilly         1
 3         Meena Kimi          2
```

Find the names of all customers who are referred by others.

**the output should be dolly dilly and meena kimi.**

I have succesfully found out for customers who have reffred others  by query

```
 SELECT c1.name FROM Customer c1 JOIN Customer c2 ON c1.custid=c2. ReferredBy
```

Comment: Please clarify your expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE ReferredBy IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think what the OP meant was creating a relationship between `CustID` and `ReferredBy`.

Comment: @Surfer513 - well that's not what he said, and this matches his desired output.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you want, but one interesting is using CTE because it allows you to get reference by level, for example in your case level zero will be `Neeta syam` that has no reference, level one is `dolly dilly` and `meena kimi`. The following query will return `dolly dilly` and `meena kimi` which are in the level one specified by `where reference = 1` like so:

```
WITH CTEs (Id, CustomerName, Reference, RefCustomer)
AS
(
  SELECT 
    Id,
    Name,
    0 As Reference, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(length), 'No Reference') AS RefCustomer 
  FROM Customers 
  WHERE ReferredBy IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.CustId,
    c.Name, 
    cs.Reference + 1, 
    cs.CustomerName 
  FROM Customers c 
  INNER JOIN Ctes cs ON c.ReferedBy = cs.Id
)
SELECT CustomerName, RefCustomer 
FROM Ctes 
WHERE Reference = 1;
```

Comment: Won't work as written, since you are `JOIN`ing on `NAME` and that's not what's used in the relation.  I think it should be `INNER JOIN Ctes cs ON c.ReferedBy = cs.Id`

Comment: cs.CustomerName is selected as RefCustomer in the union all portion

Comment: You are correct.  I'd say run it against a `#temp` table to test it